# Ethical AI - why are people discussing governance of AI and inclusion of ethics?

Tags: ethics

I mean, possibly we have seen a lot of press in last year whether X or Y should be ethical like biotech, physics.. which I completely understand. Herewith is meant actually ethics of research and science.

But why are there discussions of ethics for AI itself? (not its researchers) and regulating it?

[AI program of the German government](https://www.bundesregierung.de/resource/blob/992814/1550276/3f7d3c41c6e05695741273e78b8039f2/2018-11-15-ki-strategie-data.pdf) mentions for example "*ethics by design*".

Comment: I'm pretty sure things like "X by design" usually mean that the rules it is designed to follow are ethical, rather than any inherent decision making ability of the X.

Comment: Also, why _not_ discuss it?

Answer (score 3):

## First off, let's touch on what eithical AI is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_ethics

> Machine ethics (or machine morality, computational morality, or computational ethics) is a part of the ethics of artificial intelligence concerned with **the moral behavior of artificially intelligent beings**.

Basically, AI can (or at least, the goal is to design one that can), **behave**. That is, make decisions and act on them. The goal is to constrict that behavior to be following a set of moral/ethical rules.

Two most obvious examples are:

- If you design an AI hooked up to a weapon, presumably you want its internal design and programming preventing it from killing people (unless they are explicit and designed target)
- If you design an AI that can take matter and convert it to paperclips, presumably you want its internal design and programming preventing it from using humans - or entire earth - as paperclip materials (aka. "Paperclip Maximizer" problem in AI research).

The field is incredibly complex and can't really be covered by a single SE answer, so I'm not sure what to put in here absent more targeted and specific question

Absent specialist literature, Isaac Asimov's Robot books should serve as a good primer on the topic that isn't written for grad students specializing in either philosophy or AI.

Otherwise, I would suggest "Waking up" podcast with Sam Harris, where some episodes cover this topic in a slightly less than layperson, but very accessible level.

## Why does it enter political discussion?

- Idealistic answer:

  Because part of political discourse is making sure that human activity (including research, including research into AI) and results of that activity do not harm people or cause the world to be worse off.

  As AI has theoretical capability **and agency** to harm humans or make the world worse off, it is therefore in scope to constrain that capability and agency the way currently intelligent beings (homo sapience) are by human ethics.
- Cynical answer

  Because people like to control and regulate. And people like to Do Something. And people have reasonable and unreasonable fears. In that view frame, Ethical AI is somewhat akin to imbuing deities with morals and ethics, in hopes they don't randomly destroy humans (not that Ancient Greek deities had much in the way morals and ethics, but that's in scope for Mythology.SE, not here).

  - Some people have unreasonable fear of AI, based on lack of understanding
  - Some people have reasonable fear of AI, based on understanding (partial or full) of what it can be capable of.
  - All of those people expect their government to address those fears.